# Django query to filter username in correct format

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

There is model OraganisationUser :

```
class OrganisationUser(CommonInfo): 
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='organisation_user')
    managers = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='employees_managed', null=True, default=None, blank=True, symmetrical=False)
    approvers = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='approvees', null=True, default=None, blank=True, symmetrical=False)
    organisation = models.ForeignKey(Organisation, related_name='employees')
    user_details = models.OneToOneField('OrganisationUserDetails', null=True, blank=True)
    super_admin = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='organisation_employees', null=True, blank=True)
    objects = OrganisationUserManager()
    gems = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    rank = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
```

I have written a query to filter user name in views.py :

```
username = OrganisationUser.objects.filter(user = id)
print username

Its printing :  [<OrganisationUser: nirmal>]
```

I want to fetch **nirmal** from above result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter` returns a list of objects. Use `get` to get a single object and navigate to the username:

```
username = OrganisationUser.objects.get(user=id).user.username
```

Better yet, look up the user directly

```
username = User.objects.get(pk=id).username
```

Is there a possibility of not finding the user with that id?

Where are you getting the `id`? Is this the logged in user? Then he is available in `request.user`, and his username in `request.user.username`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that 'username' has the organisationuser object. With that object (in your code username), you can access any atribute like active,user,managers,organisation,userdetails.... just adding a dot between object and atribute.

You can do it like this:

```
orguser = OrganisationUser.objects.filter(user = id)
print orguser  #This print the object OrganisationUser
print orguser.user  #This print the object User, wich the onetoonefield is pointing to
print orguser.user.username #This print the username, of the user pointed by the one to one field
```

Example managing django object. Get attribute value:

```
object =  OrganisationUser.objects.filter(user = 1)  #Get the object with id=1
print object.active  #This will print the value for this attribute (active)
```